# Ranking algorithm with multiples factors

Tags: algorithm, math, ranking

So I'd like to rank items depending on multiples factors, however some are more important than others.

Concretely, I've a list of products which all have the following properties:

- A price
- A weight (in kilogrammes)
- A time to build (in minutes)
- A size (in centimetres)

Each property has a different scale, and I know the min & max range of them.

For example the price are between 10 and 200, while the weight are between 1.2 and 3.4, etc.

I'd like to apply a priority to the size, then to the time to build, weight and finally the price.

However, I'd like to ensure that no matter the time to build, the weight or the price values are, the size should be the first things that should matters.

For example:

```
[{
  price: 320,
  size: 10,
  weight: 0.4
  time: 4
},
{
  price: 230,
  size: 5,
  weight: 1.2
  time: 23
},
{
  price: 230,
  size: 10,
  weight: 1.2
  time: 23
}]
```

should results in:

```
[{
  price: 230,
  size: 5,             // the lowest the better
  weight: 1.2
  time: 23
},
{
  price: 320,          // the higher the better
  size: 10,
  weight: 0.4
  time: 4
},
{
  price: 230,
  size: 10,
  weight: 1.2
  time: 23
}]
```

I'm not very good at math and I don't really know where to start.

I'm thinking of something like scale each values on the same range (for example from 0 to 100) and them apply a factor the resulting range value and them add them all before to sort or something like that.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to sort by size in increasing order, then if two objects have the same size then by time in increasing order, then by weight in increasing order, then by price in *decreasing* order (according to the comment in your example).

If you are using a language like Python, just put the four values into a tuple, with the items to be in decreasing order with their values replaced with their negatives. For each item your key is

```
(size, time, weight, -price)
```

Then Python itself will sort those tuples appropriately--it is built into the language.  This is the easiest thing to do.

If you are using a language without sorted tuples, or for some reason you really want the key to be a floating point value, you can do this. For each factor, look at the known minimum and maximum. Use those to scale that factor to a number between 1 and 10, perhaps including 1 but not including 10. Make sure 1 goes with the value to be sorted first. This can be done with

```
scale1to10 = (value - min) / (max + 1 - min) * 9 + 1
```

for increasing factors, and with

```
scale1to10 = (max - value) / (max + 1 - min) * 9 + 1
```

for decreasing factors. Then combine all the factors into one "4-digit" number, as in

```
scale = scalesize * 1000 + scaletime * 100 + scaleweight * 10 + scaleprice
```

Note that the most important factor is multiplied by the highest power of 10, while the lowest has no multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting function should have the ability to pass a comparison function.  Pass a comparison function that tests each field in order, only moving to the next if everything so far is equal.  In most languages this is not too hard to do.  My guess (based on your posting history) is that you're using PHP so http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/ is likely to be the best guide to how to do that.